# How to profile multiple goroutines

Tags: go, pprof

I want to profile a server written in Go. I am using "net/http/pprof", but the default behaviour is utterly useless, as it seems to only profile the goroutine running the server that serves the profiling data.

Comment: pprof profiles the entire program. Please show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @JimB You're correct! The problem was that I needed an immense server load to see what I wanted to see.

Comment: Yes, you can't profile what the server isn't doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my server under load with siege. With 1000 concurrent users I got the profiling data that I wanted.